# Forest Trust between 2012 and 2008 DCs FAIL: Acess Denied

Tags: domain-controller, active-directory

I have 2 domains setup as 2 virtual machines.
Comminucation between them is working including NSLOOKUP and NLTEST /DSGETDC.
However, when attempting to create a trust between the 2 I end up getting:
"The operation failed. The error is: Access is Denied".

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems though when being asked to input the domain name, a FQDN must be used even though the instructions permit NETBIOS.
That nailed it for me.